# Infinite Loop when counting with an array [C]

Tags: c

I've been trying to get back into C lately (for work related purposes) and I've been to a C refresher workshop. I can't seem to get my head around why an infinite loop occurs in this code.

I'm trying to code a program which returns the number of words within an array of characters. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
// ArrayWords.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define LENGTH 50

int word_count(char []);

int main(void) {

    char sentence[LENGTH];
    int i;

    printf("Enter a sentence with at most %d characters:\n", LENGTH);

    for(i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
        scanf("%s", &sentence[i]);

    printf("Sentence = %s\n", sentence); 

    printf("Word count = %d\n", word_count(sentence));

    return 0;
}

// Count the number of words in str
int word_count(char str[]) {

    int i, word = 1;

    for(i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
        while(str[i] != '\0')
            if((isspace(str[i])))
            {   
                word++;
            }

    return word;
}
```

Comment: Did the workshop not instruct on the user of a debugger?  DCV.

Answer (score 1):

- Your use of `scanf` isn't good.
- `word_count` cause infinite loop because `i` isn't updated in the `while` loop.

fixed code:

```
// ArrayWords.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define LENGTH 50

int word_count(char []);

int main(void) {

    char sentence[LENGTH];

    printf("Enter a sentence with at most %d characters:\n", LENGTH);

    fgets(sentence, sizeof(sentence), stdin);

    printf("Sentence = %s\n", sentence); 

    printf("Word count = %d\n", word_count(sentence));

    return 0;
}

// Count the number of words in str
int word_count(char str[]) {

    int i = 0, word = 1;

    while(str[i] != '\0') {
        if((isspace(str[i])))
        {   
            word++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return word;
}
```

Comment: Maybe start `word` with `0` as `word_count()` will count the final ENTER as a word separator (and return `2` for an input with a single word). Also pay attention to consecutive spaces ...

Comment: Thanks MikeCAT.

I realized that scanf would terminate at a space so it wouldn't be appropriate in my code.

I'm wondering why variable i wouldn't be incremented in my original code though.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
    scanf("%s", &sentence[i]);
```

Here you are reading a `char` one by one. so it should have `%c`, like `scanf(" %c", &sentence[i]);`

However, this wont be the right way to read the string. Since, it wont put the `\0` in the end.

Since the string to be read will contain spaces, best way to do this would be `fgets()`

Your counting loop also has an error, either you can change it to one of the answers above or simply use a single `for` loop, like this

```
for(i = 0; i < LENGTH && str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    if((isspace(str[i])))
    {   
        word++;
    }
```

Comment: This loop replaced `%s` by `%c` won't be the right way not because the input will contain spaces but because it isn't checking for end of input and doesn't put terminating null-character.

Comment: Thanks Haris! I understand why fgets would be better now.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the program

```
for(i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
    scanf("%s", &sentence[i]);
```

does not make sense. It tries to enter `LENGTH` number of words in the loop.

I think you mean format specifier `%c` instead of `%s`

```
    scanf("%c", &sentence[i]);
```

but even in this case this snippet of code is wrong because the user can enter either less than `LENGTH` characters or even greater than `LENGTH` characters and the character array `sentence` will not be zero-terminated..

It is better to use standard function `fgets` instead of `scanf` in this situation.

And function `word_count` is also wrong. For example if `str` would be zero-terminated nevertheless the outer for loop will try to count words outside the string. And the function in fact counts the number of spaces. It is not the same as the number of words. A string can contain adjasted spaces. This mistake is made by all others in their answers.:)
And inside the while loop variable i is not increased. So it is an infinite loop.

```
int word_count(char str[]) {

    int i, word = 1;

    for(i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
        while(str[i] != '\0')
            if((isspace(str[i])))
            {   
                word++;
            }

    return word;
}
```

The program can look the following way

```
// ArrayWords.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define LENGTH 50

size_t word_count( const char[] );

int main( void )
{
    char sentence[LENGTH];

    printf( "Enter a sentence with at most %d characters: ", LENGTH );
    fgets( sentence, LENGTH, stdin );

    printf( "Sentence = \"%s\"\n", sentence ); 

    printf( "Word count = %zu\n", word_count( sentence ) );

    return 0;
}

// Count the number of words in str
size_t word_count( const char s[] ) 
{
    size_t words = 0;

    while ( *s != '\0' )
    {
        //  skip white spaces
        while ( isspace( ( unsigned char )*s ) ) ++s;

        if ( *s != '\0' ) ++words;

        //  skip the word
        while ( *s != '\0' && !isspace( ( unsigned char )*s ) ) ++s;
    }

    return words;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter a sentence with at most 50 characters: Hello, Unholy Wish
Sentence = "Hello, Unholy Wish"
Word count = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code,`i` isn't actually in the loop.Besides,array contains the sentence with a `\0` in the end,so if the length of the sentence is 50,the space must be 51 since at the end of it there is an `\0`,and `scanf` is not so good as it judges `" "`as a stop sign,`gets` can't stop until enter key which may cause overflow,so I use `fgets`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define LENGTH 50
int word_count(char []);
int main(void) {
    char sentence[LENGTH+1];
    printf("Enter a sentence with at most %d characters:\n", LENGTH);
    fgets(sentence, sizeof(sentence), stdin);
    printf("Sentence = %s\n", sentence);
    printf("Word count = %d\n", word_count(sentence));
    return 0;
}

// Count the number of words in str
int word_count(char str[]) {
    char* p=str;
    int word=0;
    while(*p!='\0'){
        if((isspace(*p))) word++;
        p++;
    }
    return word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read data from stdin, not scanf but fgets or gets!
Maybe fgets( sentence, LENGTH, stdin ) is good.
And in the function word_count you may replace while with if.

Comment: `scanf` reads from `stdin`! How does this answer the question?

Comment: it does!sorry, that I really want to express is that scanf can't reads a sentence from stdin , because scanf if returned when it encount space.

Answer (score -1):

It's not an infinite loop.

Your program is trying to read 50 (or `LENGTH`) words (and saving them on top of each other).

```
    for(i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
        scanf("%s", &sentence[i]);
```

Put first word starting at `sentence[0]`;
put second word starting at `sentence[1]` overwriting characters from the first word;
...